# How do I get upload progress for web request

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tried to use `progressMessageHandler` from `Net.Http.Handlers` namespace but I got

> The type or namespace name 'Handlers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Things I have tried:

- Visual studio's Add reference. not working cause unity
  download System.Net.Http dll and put it to unity dll's not working too
- update System.Net.Http from nuget

My current code is:

```
public static async Task<string> Upload(string uri, string pathFile)
    {

        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathFile);

        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("*/*");

            //Send it
            var response = await nftClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359). What are you trying to use that namespace for?

Comment: for progressMessageHandler , I have HTTP ClIENT to Upload my file to server . And Show my user Upload progress

Comment: handler.HttpSendProgress += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            float prog = (float)e.BytesTransferred / (float)bytes.Length;
                            prog = prog > 1 ? 1 : prog;
                            print(prog);
                        };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `UnityWebRequest` and use `uploadProgress` to update the progress:

```
UnityWebRequest uwr;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PutRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com"));
    StartCoroutine(UploadProgressCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator PutRequest(string url)
{
    byte[] dataToPut = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, This is a test");
    uwr = UnityWebRequest.Put(url, dataToPut);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}

IEnumerator UploadProgressCoroutine()
{
    while (!uwr.isDone)
    {
        HandleProgress(uwr.uploadProgress);
        yield return null;
    }
}

void HandleProgress(float currentProgress)
{
    // currentProgress is value between 0 and 1
}
```

Based on **Programmer**'s code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46008025/1092820).

Or for your specific use case, you will need to create your own `UnityWebRequest` to get the headers and data the way your server expects:

```
UnityWebRequest uwr;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PostRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com", "/file/path/here"));
    StartCoroutine(UploadProgressCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator PostRequest(string url, string filePath)
{
    byte[] dataToPost = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    uwr = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST", new DownloadHandlerBuffer(),
            new UploadHandlerRaw(dataToPost));

    uwr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "*/*");
    uwr.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
    uwr.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken);

    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}

IEnumerator UploadProgressCoroutine()
{
    while (!uwr.isDone)
    {
        HandleProgress(uwr.uploadProgress);
        yield return null;
    }
}

void HandleProgress(float currentProgress)
{
    // currentProgress is value between 0 and 1
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, But it created other problems

Comment: my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71335381/http-client-upload-file-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment126092024_71335381

Comment: @ArIaNFury "Created other problems" doesn't describe what happened or didnt happen, only that it didn't meet your expectation. Please be more descriptive. Including your code was helpful. See my edit.

Comment: i'll check now thanks

Comment: it works fine but there is problem I cant get information from api      Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text); give me wrong info                    how can put DefaultRequestHeaders ? such nftClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");  and nftClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken);

Comment: amazing thanks. I just add uwr.SetRequestHeader and worked as should be

Comment: @ArIaNFury great, i added those to my answer